# reRender Outputpanel is not working

Tags: visualforce, rerender

VF Page:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" docType="html-5.0" controller="assignStudentsFinal1">   
        <apex:form >
           <div class="slds-button-group" role="group">
                <apex:commandButton id="filter" styleclass="btn btn-primary" value="Go" action="{!getEngagements}" reRender="datePanelContainer,studentTable"/>                 
           </div>
           <apex:outputpanel id="studentTable" rendered="{!itFailed}" >
                 <apex:outputPanel id="datePanelContainer" rendered="{!itFailed}" >
                       This is for testing
                  </apex:outputPanel>
           </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:form>
  </apex:page>
```

Class:

```
public class assignStudentsFinal1 {

 public boolean itFailed  {get;set;}

 public assignStudentsFinal1 ()
 {
    itFailed = false; 
 } 

 public void getEngagements(){
     itFailed  =true;    
 }
```

**Issue**:
On click of command button, output panel is not reRendering. I know I am doing a silly mistake which I am unable to find out.

**Updated Actual VF:**

```
 <div class="slds-button-group" role="group">
                  <apex:commandButton id="filter" styleclass="btn btn-primary" value="Go" action="{!getEngagements}" reRender="studentTable"/> 
                  <apex:commandButton styleclass="btn btn-primary" value="Update Records" action="{!updateEngagements}" rerender="myForm,thePanelWrapper" status="statusSaveTrip"  />  

              </div>             

      </form>
      <br/>
        <apex:outputpanel id="studentTable">
            <apex:outputPanel id="datePanelContainer" rendered="{!wrapList.size != 0}">
            <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--fixed-layout" role="grid">
              <thead>
                <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
                  <th class="slds-cell-shrink" scope="col">
                    <label class="slds-checkbox">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="options" onchange="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'inputId')" />
                      <span class="slds-checkbox--faux"></span>
                      <span class="slds-assistive-text">Select All</span>
                    </label>
                  </th>
                  <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-is-resizable" scope="col" aria-label="Opportunity Name">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-th__action slds-text-link--reset">
                      <span class="slds-assistive-text">Sort </span>
                      <span class="slds-truncate" title="Opportunity Name">Student Engagement</span>
                      <div class="slds-icon_container">
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-is-sortable__icon">
                          <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#arrowdown"></use>
                        </svg>
                      </div>
                      <span class="slds-assistive-text" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true"></span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="slds-resizable">
                      <label for="cell-resize-handle-203" class="slds-assistive-text">Opportunity Name column width</label>
                      <input class="slds-resizable__input slds-assistive-text" type="range" min="20" max="1000" id="cell-resize-handle-203" />
                      <span class="slds-resizable__handle">
                        <span class="slds-resizable__divider"></span>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </th>
                  <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-is-resizable" scope="col" aria-label="Account Name">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-th__action slds-text-link--reset">
                      <span class="slds-assistive-text">Sort </span>
                      <span class="slds-truncate" title="Account Name">Learning Community</span>
                      <div class="slds-icon_container">
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-is-sortable__icon">
                          <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#arrowdown"></use>
                        </svg>
                      </div>
                      <span class="slds-assistive-text" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true"></span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="slds-resizable">
                      <label for="cell-resize-handle-204" class="slds-assistive-text">Account Name column width</label>
                      <input class="slds-resizable__input slds-assistive-text" type="range" min="20" max="1000" id="cell-resize-handle-204" />
                      <span class="slds-resizable__handle">
                        <span class="slds-resizable__divider"></span>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </th>
                  <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-is-resizable" scope="col" aria-label="Close Date">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-th__action slds-text-link--reset">
                      <span class="slds-assistive-text">Sort </span>
                      <span class="slds-truncate" title="Close Date">Current Track</span>
                      <div class="slds-icon_container">
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-is-sortable__icon">
                          <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#arrowdown"></use>
                        </svg>
                      </div>
                      <span class="slds-assistive-text" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true"></span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="slds-resizable">
                      <label for="cell-resize-handle-205" class="slds-assistive-text">Close Date column width</label>
                      <input class="slds-resizable__input slds-assistive-text" type="range" min="20" max="1000" id="cell-resize-handle-205" />
                      <span class="slds-resizable__handle">
                        <span class="slds-resizable__divider"></span>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </th>
                  <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-is-resizable" scope="col" aria-label="Stage">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-th__action slds-text-link--reset">
                      <span class="slds-assistive-text">Sort </span>
                      <span class="slds-truncate" title="Stage">New Track</span>
                      <div class="slds-icon_container">
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-is-sortable__icon">
                          <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#arrowdown"></use>
                        </svg>
                      </div>
                      <span class="slds-assistive-text" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true"></span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="slds-resizable">
                      <label for="cell-resize-handle-206" class="slds-assistive-text">Stage column width</label>
                      <input class="slds-resizable__input slds-assistive-text" type="range" min="20" max="1000" id="cell-resize-handle-206" />
                      <span class="slds-resizable__handle">
                        <span class="slds-resizable__divider"></span>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </th>

                  <th class="slds-cell-shrink" scope="col"></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <apex:repeat value="{!wrapList}" var="e">  
                    <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                      <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-shrink" data-label="Select row Engagement">
                        <label class="slds-checkbox">                          
                          <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!e.selected}" id="inputId"/>          
                          <span class="slds-checkbox--faux"></span>
                          <span class="slds-assistive-text">Select row Engagement</span>
                        </label>
                      </td>         
                      <td role="gridcell" data-label="Account Name">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Cloudhub"><apex:outputText value="{!e.eng.name}" /></div>
                      </td>  
                      <td>
                        <apex:selectList styleclass="slds-input" value="{!e.selectedLC}" size="1" id="lcoption">                                                                              
                              <apex:selectOptions value="{!e.selectedCLC}"/> 
                                    <apex:param value="{!e.rowcount}" assignTo="{!count}" name="count"/> 
                        </apex:selectList>
                      </td>   
                      <td><apex:outputText value="{!e.selectedNTrack}" id="track" /></td>  
                      <td> 
                         <apex:selectList styleclass="slds-input" id="trackv" value="{!e.selectedNTrack}" size="1">                                                                           
                               <apex:selectOptions value="{!e.selectedTrack}"/>
                                     <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!refreshPage}" rerender="track" > 
                                           <apex:param value="{!e.rowcount}" assignTo="{!count}" name="count"/>
                               </apex:actionSupport>                                                                            
                         </apex:selectList>
                      </td>    
                    </tr>  
                 </apex:repeat>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>
```

**Actual method in Class:**

```
public void getEngagements(){
     //lcOptionslist();
      if(wrapList!=null)
     wrapList.clear();    
     integer i=0;       
     wrapList = new list<WrapperClass>();        
     String Query= 'SELECT id, Name, Site__c,Track_Assignment__c,Sample__c, Learning_Community__c,Cohort__c,Learning_Community__r.Name FROM Engagement__c WHERE (Cohort__c=:selectedCohort AND Site__c=:selectedSite)';        
        if(assignUassign=='Unassigned'){            
            Query += ' AND Learning_Community__c=null';  
        }else if(assignUassign=='Assigned'){            
            Query += ' AND Learning_Community__c!=null';  
            System.debug('Query '+Query );
        }

     for(Engagement__c eng : Database.query(Query)){  
            if(eng.Learning_Community__c==null){            
                wrapList.add(new WrapperClass(eng,trackOptions,'--None--',Lcoptions,'--Unassigned--',i,getTrackspecialities(eng.id))); 
                System.debug('wrapList '+wrapList);           
            } else{            
                wrapList.add(new WrapperClass(eng,trackOptions,eng.Track_Assignment__c,Lcoptions,eng.Learning_Community__c,i,getTrackspecialities(eng.id)));   
            }           
            i++;
        } 
 }
```

Regards,
Ajay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever we try to refresh a `outputPanel` or `div` through the `reRender`, that `OutputPanel` must be available on the page.

In the case, `itFailed` is `false` during page load. So the `studentTable` panel is not rendered.

Corrected code is below:

So, remove `rendered="{!itFailed}"` from the `studentTable` to make it workable.

```
      <div class="slds-button-group" role="group">
            <apex:commandButton id="filter" styleclass="btn btn-primary" value="Go" action="{!getEngagements}" reRender="datePanelContainer,studentTable"/>                 
       </div>
       <apex:outputpanel id="studentTable">
             <apex:outputPanel id="datePanelContainer" rendered="{!itFailed}" >
                   This is for testing
              </apex:outputPanel>
       </apex:outputPanel>
```

**Update**

To stop full page refresh, you have to use actionFunction in conjunction with `CommandButton` click event

```
<apex:commandButton id="filter" styleclass="btn btn-primary" value="Go"  onclick="doFilterCheck();return false;"/> 

<apex:actionFunction name="actionDoCheck" action="{!getEngagements}"  rerender="studentTable"/>
```

write a small `javascript` to call this `actionFunction`

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response. That was example derived from actual problem which is there in my class. I have just added my actual VF page and method in class. which is not working, if I remove reRender, then it will load entire page. What am I missing?